which is something you often do
a. Tom blames himself and Jack does too.
Could that sentence mean that Jack blames Tom too, or does it always mean that Jack blames himself?
b. I talked to my mother, and you did too.
I think that one is clearly ambiguous.

I talked to my mother and you talked to her too.

I talked to my mother and you talked to yours.


But how about
c. I haven't talked to my mother in three weeks, but you have.
d. I haven't talked to my mother in three weeks, which is something you often do.
In (c) is it possible that you have talked to your mother?
In (d) is it possible that you talk to your mother often and not to mine?
I think in linguistics this problem is called 'sloppy identity'.
Many thanks

All your sentences are technically ambiguous. (Did you mean to put 'and but'?)

Thank you very much, Kate. No that was a mistake. I'd like to say it was a typo, but "typo" seems too small a word for such a big mistake. My brain probably did a U-turn somewhere without telling me!

In (c) and (d) you'd probably have some context. If you'd each been talking about when you last saw your respective families, vs if you'd both been talking about the same person's family. I can't imagine saying either without some kind of context or introduction. Although it might still be ambiguous.
